# Is Nested datatype still supported in Elasticsearch 6?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

After reading this article on [Removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) I am confused if Nested datatype is still supported in ElasticSearch 6.x. I have been using the following document structure with two different document types placed in one index:

```
    public class ProductDoc
    {
        long ProductId { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        long BranchId { get; set; }
        decimal Rating { get; set; }
        DateTime PublishedAt { get; set; }

        [Nested]
        ICollection<VariantDoc> Variants { get; set; }
    }

    public class VariantDoc
    {
         long VariantId { get; set; }
         decimal Price { get; set; }
         int Quantity { get; set; }
         List<string> Features { get; set; }
    }
```

Since keeping different document types in the same index is not possible anymore as referred in the blog post, I wonder how I can organize this index structure. 
One possible way would be to make a flat normalized object `VariantDoc` for each variant of the product, in which I will move all the properties from the ProductDoc to the VariantDoc. This is what I would get:

```
public class VariantDoc
{
     long VariantId { get; set; }
     decimal Price { get; set; }
     int Quantity { get; set; }
     List<string> Features { get; set; }

    long ProductId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    long BranchId { get; set; }
    decimal Rating { get; set; }
    DateTime PublishedAt { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't think this is smart because I'd need to duplicate so much data especially because a single product can even have 60 variants.

Comment: `nested` data types are supported, since the structure are still part of the parent type i.e. `Variants` collection property is part of the `ProductDoc` mapping

Answer (score 0):

[`nested` data types are supported](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), since the structure are still part of the parent type. In your example, `Variants` collection property is part of the `ProductDoc` mapping.

What is no longer supported in Elasticsearch 6.0+ is to have multiple types within a single index; only a single type name can be specified, which you can decide what this is. In a future major version, this type name will also be removed.